# CentOs 6 as Firewall, forward traffic from eth1 to eth0 -> destination host prohibited

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables, nat, forward

I'm setting up Firewall with a CentOs 6.0 for testing. I'm doing this on two virtualmachines.

First VM (Firewall) has 2 interface:
 eth0 - connected to NAT with 10.0.2.10, access to internet
 eth1 - connected to local vm network with 20.0.0.1

Second VM (Server) has 1 interface:
 eth0 - connected to local vm network with 20.0.0.2, GATEWAY 20.0.0.1.

They both have static ip's and dns. What I want to do is that Server have inet access via Firewall VM, to do that I've done those configurations:

VM1-Firewall:
/etc/sysctl.conf net.ipv4.ip_forward 1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT

VM2-Server:
Just set that the gateway is the firewall 20.0.0.1 and DNS is 8.8.8.8

When I try to ping, for example, 8.8.8.8 it says Destination Host Prohibited.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think it's iptables doesnt redirect traffic from eth1 to eth0 but it should do with this config, no?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide `iptables --list --verbose` form both VMs. Can you ping 8.8.8.8 from VM1?

Comment: Hi @dusan.bajic , here's a pic of both machines: http://i58.tinypic.com/15ho2e1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to default denying firewall policy you should rather use

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

-A option appends the rule at the **end** of iptables chain. The default drop policy will firstly drop the packet and ignore further matching rules.

Comment: Hi @Maciej%Asembler , I've done what you say but still Host Prohibited, I've uploaded a pic of both iptables http://i58.tinypic.com/15ho2e1.jpg

Thanks!